# JavaFX Webview & Azure auth & Spring Mystic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I came across an interesting story, I have a web service on `Spring Boot` `3.1.5`, I attached `Azure ldap` auth to it the server itself plays the role of the “brain” in the architecture,
in the form of a view, I create a desktop on `javafx` + `spring` on its rests, from the desktop to the server I go through the usual `RestTemplate` (I don’t add any additional headers), and there is an interesting situation, when in the `javafx webview` I log in to the server (the server has a default view), then, by some miracle, I can also use `RestTemplate` make get requests to the server (although in theory the requests should not have gone through, because I do not send absolutely any headers; in the debug, `Spring` also did not send any cookies, i.e. the requests should have failed due to non-authorization).

This `webview` in which I log in does not reflect any business logic, i.e. this is not an authorization panel, I was playing for the sake of a test, and I noticed such an interesting joke.

What I did to find out the problem:

I used `wireshark`, it showed that indeed, someone was throwing cookies into my request.

I checked the call to `HttpURLConnection.setDefaultRequestProperty()`, no one called this method.

Made a request to the server in another thread, as a result the request was successful, a header was also added to it.

I didn’t see also any headers in the debug, and let me remind you again that I don’t put any headers in the request.

My code for sending request, its simple request:

```
return restTemplate.getForEntity(path, response).getBody();
```

and simple `restTemplate` config:

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(AdminHost adminHost) {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
```

`Query` before auth (data from `wireShark`):

```
GET /consumer/all HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
User-Agent: Java/17.0.6
Host: localhost:8585
Connection: keep-alive
```

`Query` after auth:

```
   GET /consumer/all HTTP/1.1
   Accept: application/json, application/*+json
   User-Agent: Java/17.0.6
   Host: localhost:8585
   Connection: keep-alive
   Cookie: JSESSIONID=F90C8BCEADE10470F641D2E5138A1034
```

and another fact that blew my mind,

if I use the previous configuration, then what I described above happens, but if I change the configuration as follows, that is, I simply configure the `restTemplate` on a specific host, then everything changes, the session is still thrown into the header, but this session is either broken, or not active, because the request does not go through.

Here config:

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(AdminHost adminHost) {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri(adminHost.getHost()).build();
  }
```

Here differend beetwen requests.

Failed request with new config:

```
GET /consumer/all HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:8585
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.6)
Cookie:JSESSIONID=A568E0B7A760E211F275DBBE6CE67BDF
```

Success request with old config:

```
GET /consumer/all HTTP/1.1
   Accept: application/json, application/*+json
   User-Agent: Java/17.0.6
   Host: localhost:8585
   Connection: keep-alive
   Cookie: JSESSIONID=F90C8BCEADE10470F641D2E5138A1034
```

`cookies` are inserted into any request, I made a request through `RestTemplate`, `Apache` and even native `Java` tools, in any of them a session is ultimately inserted,

so, a few questions:

1. why, how and from where a cookie is inserted into my request after authorization in the webview, which is independent of my manual requests
2. Why, after changing the configuration of the restTemplate to a specific host, everything went wrong and requests began to fail?
3. what's going on...

Comment: Please don't screenshot text.  Put text in the question as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering unexpected behavior with cookies being automatically added to your requests after authentication in the webview, as well as issues with requests failing after changing the configuration of RestTemplate. Let's break down your questions:

Why, how, and from where a cookie is inserted into my request after authorization in the webview?

It's likely that the webview is storing the session cookie upon authentication and automatically including it in subsequent requests made from the same webview instance. This behavior is common in web applications where sessions are maintained using cookies. The webview might be handling session management internally, which is why you're not explicitly seeing any code adding headers.

Why, after changing the configuration of the RestTemplate to a specific host, everything went wrong and requests began to fail?

When you change the configuration of RestTemplate to a specific host, it seems like the session cookie being included in the request is not valid for that specific host or context. This could be due to various reasons such as domain restrictions on cookies, session expiration, or differences in session management between different parts of your application.

What's going on?

It appears that there might be differences in how session management is handled between the webview authentication process and the RestTemplate requests. The webview might be managing sessions independently of your manual requests, which is why you're seeing unexpected behavior when using RestTemplate.

Comment: ok, but where does the webview store session data? I’m interested in how this mechanism works from the inside. Cookies don’t appear out of thin air in my request. Do you know where and at what level they are thrown?  and what exactly can influence this